# how to implement jobpost functionality that has 3 fixed categoris

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model, associations, model-associations

What i want to do is create placement model which will be used to post jobs for 3 fixed categories i.e internship,corporate and freelance.There will be a menu of placement which will have 3 menues as internship,corporate and freelance and based on user selection ,for these 3 categories same job post form will be shown for creating job posts.
While showing jobposts diffrent view  will be shown based on category.

I am not getting how i should implement this.Whether i should create placement and categories as a different model and give association as has-many categories in placement and belongsto placement in category, but if i do that way,in categories model i have 3 fixed choices and i am not going to accept that choice from user,so how can i add these 3 choices in the model which will be fixed and add jobposts for them categorywise?

How can i implement this placement thing?

Answer (score 0):

It's simple you can achieve in various ways one way is create job_type which has one of 3 categories and give dropdown while creating job post.

For easy to find out create scope for 3 categories like

```
scope :freelance,where("job_type = ?",'freelance') ....
```

`JobPost.freelance` gives freelance job post.

Answer (score 0):

Define the models as

```
Class Jobpost
  belongs_to :resource, :polymorphic => true, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :resource
  def resource_attributes=(params = {})
    self.resource = spec_type.constantize.new unless self.resource
    self.resource.attributes = params.select{|k| self.resource.attribute_names.include?(k) || self.resource.class::ACCESSOR.include?(k.to_sym)}
   end
end

class Freelancer
  has_one :jobpost, :as => :resource
end
```

Add fields to Jobpost as to create fields(resource_id: integer, resource_type: string)

```
#jobposts table
t.references :resource, :polymorphic => true
```

The view as

```
= form_for(@jobpost, :url => jobposts_path, :method => :post) do |f|
   = fields of Jobpost
   = f.fields_for :resource, build_resource('freelancer') do |freelancer|
     = fields of Freelancer
```

The Jobpost helper as

```
module JobpostsHelper
  def build_resource(klass)
    klass  = "{klass.capitalize}"
    object = eval("#{klass}.new")
    if @jobpost.resource.class.name == klass
      object = @jobpost.resource
    end
    return object
  end
end
```

Use javascript to show the fields of subcategory(freelancer, etc) when the link for Freelancer is clicked. when the form is submitted, all the fields for all the subcategories are submitted but they are filtered out in the 'resource_attributes=' method.