# rails model subclassing -> multi table inheritance or polymorphism

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Here is my setup, followed by an explanation of what I am trying to accomplish.

```
class Layer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :components
end

class Component < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :layers 
end

class ImageComponent < Component
  # I want this table to inherit from the Component table
  # I should be able to add image-specific fields to this table
end

class VideoComponent < Component
  # I want this table to inherit from the Component table
  # I should be able to add video-specific fields to this table
end
```

What I want to be able to do:

```
layer.components << ImageComponent.create
layer.components << VideoComponent.create
```

In practice, I realize that `ImageComponent` and `VideoComponent` will actually have to inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base`. Is there any way to nicely implement model subclassing in Rails?

Right now I have my `Component` model setup to be `polymorphic` such that `ImageComponent` and `VideoComponent` each `has_one :component, as: :componentable`. This adds a layer of annoyance and ugliness to my code though:

```
image_component = ImageComponent.create
component = Component.create
component.componentable = image_component
layer.components << component
```

I guess a simple way to explain this is that I want to implement a habtm relationship between Layers and Components. I have multiple types of Components (i.e. ImageComponent, VideoComponent) that each have the same base structure but different fields associated with them. Any suggestions on ways this can be accomplished? I feel that I am missing something because my code feels hackish.

Comment: I think the inheritance as such should work (that is, `create` should be a method of `ImageComponent`) but the AR stuff will not, because it makes assumptions about file and table names and the like based on class names.  While I think most of the Rails magic can be overridden, maybe the better approach is to keep things DRY and clean is to use a mixin, rather than straight-up inheritance.

Comment: what exactly is the problem? rails implements model subclassing. and what does all this have to do with polymorphism vs multi table inheritance?

Comment: Polymorphism and multi table inheritance are two approaches to what I am trying to do, but neither approach is particularly DRY for my situation. I want to combine multi-table inheritance with model subclassing. AFAIK you can't create a subclass of a model that gives a new table to the subclass. The subclasses I have in the example above are incapable of implementing their own fields -- they are bounded to the fields of the superclass.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "official" way to achieve this in Rails is to use Single Table Inheritance. Support for STI is built into ActiveRecord: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#class-ActiveRecord::Base-label-Single+table+inheritance

If you want to use Multi Table Inheritance you would have to implement it by yourself...

Comment: Thanks. This was my original implementation, but it felt so messy that the subclass-specific fields were available to all subclasses. i.e. if I want to add a field just to an ImageComponent, it is also available to a VideoComponent. sigh.

Comment: While fields are accessible, each subclass can have different validations. So for a `VideoComponent` you could explicitly specify that some fields should be blank. But I can imagine there is a lot of possible overlap between an `ImageComponent` and `VideComponent` so STI seems like the best solution to me in this case. If you really want to dry up your data-model, you could use a `Properties` table, where each component `has_many :properties`. HTH.

Answer (score 2):

here the main issue is between the **Component and its types** and not Layer and Component. i had a similar problem. will explain the solution specific to ur problem.

Store the type(Image/Video) as resource for Component and have a controller for Component and not all the types()

let the model structure be as

```
Component < ActiveRecord::Base
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :resource
  belongs_to :resource, :polymorphic => true, :dependent => :destroy

  def resource_attributes=(params = {})
    self.resource = spec_type.constantize.new unless self.resource
    self.resource.attributes = params.select{|k| self.resource.attribute_names.include?(k) || self.resource.class::ACCESSOR.include?(k.to_sym)}
  end

#component will be either image or video and not both

Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :component, as :resource 

Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :component, as :resource
```

and a single controller as ComponentsController for CRUD of Component. Since the Component accepts attributes for resource(ie image/video), u can save the component as well as the resource and add normal validations for each resource.

the basic view for adding a Component can be as

```
= form_for(@component, :url => components_path, :method => :post) do |f|
  = fields of Component
  = f.fields_for :resource, build_resource('image') do |image|
    = fields of resource Image
  = f.fields_for :resource, build_resource('video') do |video|
    = fields of resource Video
```

the fields for Image/Video can be added using the helper method

```
module ComponentsHelper
  def build_resource(klass)
    klass  = "{klass.capitalize}"
    object = eval("#{klass}.new")
    if @component.resource.class.name == klass
      object = @component.resource
    end
    return object
  end
end
```

since the Component can have only one related resource(image/video), u need to select the the resource type on the view(in my case it was a dropdown list) and depending upon the selected resource show its fields and hide/remove all other resources fields(if image is selected, remove video fields using javascript). When the form is submitted, the method from Component model filters out all the key-value pairs for the intended resource and creates the component and its related resource.

Also

1) keep the field names for each resource unique cause when the form is submitted, the hidden resource(unwanted resources) fields are submitted which overwrite the intended resource fields.

2) the above model structure gives problem for **resource attr_accessor only**(they are not accessible on rails console). it can be solved as

```
ACCESSOR = ['accessor1', 'accessor2'] #needed accessors
has_one :component, :as => :resource
attr_accessor *ACCESSOR
```

See [how to implement jobpost functionality that has 3 fixed categoris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534270/how-to-implement-jobpost-functionality-that-has-3-fixed-categoris/12154330#12154330)

i hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

With STI, you are sharing the same table with several model classes, so if you want subclassed models to have unique fields (database columns), then they need to be represented in that common table. From the comments in your example, it appears that this is what you want.

There is a trick you can do, however, which involves having a string column in the table that each model can use to store custom serialized data. In order to do this, it has to be OK that these data elements aren't indexed, because you won't be able to easily search on them within SQL. Let's say you call this field `aux`. Put this in the parent model:

```
  require 'ostruct'
  serialize :aux, OpenStruct
```

Now let's say you want the fields called `manager` and `experience` in a subclassed model, but none of the other STI models need this field and you won't need to search based on these attributes. So you can do this in the subclassed model:

```
# gets the value
def manager
  return self.aux.manager
end

# sets the value
def manager=(value)
  self.aux.manager = value
end

 # gets the value
def experience
  return self.aux.experience
end

# sets the value
def experience=(value)
  self.aux.experience = value
end
```

In this example, single table inheritance still works fine and you also get custom persistant attributes for subclassed models. This gives you the benefits of sharing code and database resources among several models, but also allows each model to have unique attributes.